# nib2objc: command not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nib

I've been trying to convert NIB files to Objective C code. I found the project NIB2OBJC on GitHub: https://github.com/akosma/nib2objc but when I type the command line:

nib2objc tab.xib > tab.m

I got the following error:
-bash: nib2objc: command not found

Could you tell me what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in the folder where nib2objc is located, then you've to run `./nib2objc`. Otherwise, if it's located in `/bin/`, `/usr/bin/` or any other folder in `$PATH`, then make sure that it has execution permissions:

```
$ which nib2objc
/foo/bar/nib2objc
$ stat /foo/bar/nib2objc
$ chmod a+x /foo/bar/nib2objc
```

Good luck!